# Keycloak return url

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Keycloak version 16.1.1

```
 keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(async function (authenticated: any) {
        if (!authenticated) {
          display error...
        } else {
             use  token to call rest and go to account page
        }
```

This all works fine.  After login, account page is displayed with url

http://localhost:4200/accnt

After couple of second, page flickers and url changes to

http://localhost:4200/accnt#state=5758b505-a101-48a3-a3a2-d899bf3e0da2&session_state=a5d6e548-9ebc-4666-bc41-e92f00e4f216&code=8c93d0cf-5dde-40f3-bf1f-e81d2449f1d5.a5d6e548-9ebc-4666-bc41-e91a00e4f216.c7b376cb-05a2-49fa-8164-b8c932598bbd

Why is it happening and how can I stop this flicker and url change ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `initOptions` from `{ onLoad: 'login-required' }` to

```
{
  onLoad: 'check-sso',
  silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html',
}
```

And adding a `silent-check-sso.html` file next to your `index.html` with a content:

```
<html><body><script>parent.postMessage(location.href, location.origin)</script></body></html>
```

Hope it helps!